# Command not found handler

Tags: bash

Apologies if this has been asked before, but it's basically impossible to search for.

When I type e.g. `wibble` at the bash prompt, it prints

```
Command 'wibble' not found, did you mean:
  command 'wobble' from deb emboss (6.6.0+dfsg-11ubuntu1)
Try: sudo apt install <deb name>
```

Now what I'd like to know is where is this handler and can I replace it with my own script.
For example if I were to paste a github url at the command line with no 'git clone' before it, then expand it to 'git clone', and other urls launch in Chrome, or whatever.

I can't find where this 'command not found' hander is, but I suspect it's a script somewhere that gets hooked into bash.

Comment: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/command-not-found  *you didn't provide a release and I'm not going to look up the package version for `emboss` thus the link I provided.. Had I had a release I'd have provided link that was easier & showed the files involved... (*but you can follow links yourself*)

Comment: `set -x; wibble; set +x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The handler itself is a *shell function*:

```
$ declare -f -p command_not_found_handle 
command_not_found_handle () 
{ 
    if [ -x /usr/lib/command-not-found ]; then
        /usr/lib/command-not-found -- "$1";
        return $?;
    else
        if [ -x /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found ]; then
            /usr/share/command-not-found/command-not-found -- "$1";
            return $?;
        else
            printf "%s: command not found\n" "$1" 1>&2;
            return 127;
        fi;
    fi
}
```

The default handler in Ubuntu is defined in the `/etc/bash.bashrc` file. In turn, `/usr/lib/command-not-found` is a Python script provided by the `command-not-found` package.

Comment: Thanks. Exactly what I was after.